# RoR: MyModel.descendants returns [] in a view after the first call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to display a selection list of MyModel subclasses in a view.  It's not working yet, so for sanity checking, I included this in my view:

```
<%= MyModel.descendants %>
```

The *first* time I render this page after re-starting the server, it shows the list of descendants (there are six).  All *subsequent* times, it shows up as an empty list `[]`.

FWIW, I have a `require` statement in my initializers:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("app/models/my_models/**/*.rb").to_s].each {|f| require f}
```

... and I've verified that they're getting required.

What the @($%& is going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use require, even if your `my_model.rb` gets reloaded, the kernel won't require your subclasses `.rb` files because they have already been loaded. You'd have to go through rails autoload.

Basically, on your first request, rails autoloads `MyModel` from `my_model.rb`, which then requires `my_models/sub_model.rb`. The `SubModel` class inherits `MyModel`, which populates the `descendants` array.
On your following requests, though, rails autoloads `MyModel`again (hey, you're in dev mode), which then requires `my_models/sub_model.rb` again. But this time, the kernel knows it had already loaded this file and won't load it again.

I ran into this problem one hour ago, which lead me to your post, and to find a solution. What we need is rails to autoload subclasses everytime your main class is called.

Here is a solution :

```
class MyModel
  Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),"my_models","*.rb")].each do |f|
    MyModels.const_get(File.basename(f,'.rb').classify)
  end
end
```

These lines could probably be put outside of the class. That should be enough (it is for me) if you only have files in `my_models` and not in subdirectories. If you have some (for example `MyModels::Car::Ford`, you may need to put the same kind of stuff in the submodules (in `my_models/car.rb`).

Comment: +1 for the lucid explanation of what is going on -- thank you.  Unfortunately, my sub-classes have "acronym" names, like "PGEService" with filenames like 'pge_service.rb'.  I'm not ready to rename my files to 'p_g_e_service.rb' -- at least not yet!

Comment: Well, if your files are named PGEService.rb, you can just use the file name (without the `.classify`), but I don't see any easy solution if it's still `pge_service.rb`... Unless of course you do something like `s=File.basename(f,'.rb').split('_'); class_name = s.first.upcase + s.last.classify; MyModels.const_get(class_name)`. Yeah, a bit ugly, I know.

Comment: strictly speaking, you DID answer my question of "what's going on".  So you deserve the checkmark.  I have refined my question, but I'll post that as a separate question.  Onwards!

Comment: Actually I've changed a bit the code in my model, because I would get wrong stuff when loading Subclasses : If I load `SubModel` when `MyModel` hasn't been loaded, Rails find at the `class SubModel < Model` line that it needs to load `MyModel`, which in turn requires my submodel file ... infinite loop.

The solution is to directly have the snippet above in the descendants method.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. Solved it by adding a `config/initializers/preload_models.rb` with:

```
Dir[Rails.root + 'app/models/*.rb'].map {|f| File.basename(f, '.*').camelize.constantize }
```

Hope that helps somebody.

Comment: This also still falls out of memory after a few minutes, when just loaded via initializer.

Comment: This seems to be working for me for namespaced models: `Dir[Rails.root + 'app/models/**/*.rb'].map { |f| File.path(f).to_s.sub(Rails.root.to_s + '/app/models/', '').chomp('.rb').camelize.constantize if !File.path(f).to_s.include?('/concerns/') }`, although I'm not sure if excluding concerns means models that should be loaded aren't loaded. It's not an issue in my current case.

Answer (score 7):

I just enabled eager loading in each environment:

`config.eager_load = true`

This worked for me even when using namespaces for class names.

Comment: I *think* this will be the winning answer.  Can someone else verify that this works?

Comment: This is a false positive, it will work for a few minutes, then fall out of memory. Whatever page youre using this feature with - just refresh enough, and eventually, the `descendants` or `subclasses` will start returning blank again.