# Rails Load an array of subclasses from a folder automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working with heritage on rails models. I have this class on the file:

`models/custom_class.rb`

```rb
class CustomClass < ApplicationRecord
    def self.available_from_my_class
        [
            CustomClasses::CustomClassA,
            CustomClasses::CustomClassB,
            CustomClasses::CustomClassC,
            (...)
        ]
    end

    def self.type
        raise "You must override this method in each model inheriting from CustomClass"
    end
end
```

That works fine and loads an array, but I have to declare each subclass manually.

Then I have a folder with that classes:

```
models/custom_classes/custom_class_a.rb
models/custom_classes/custom_class_b.rb
models/custom_classes/custom_class_c.rb
```

With the code that inheritance in each:

```
class CustomClasses::CustomClassA < CustomClass
    def self.to_s
        "Custom Class A"
    end


    def self.type
        "CustomClassA"
    end
end
```

I would like to know how could I load an array of all the subclasses on the folder `models/custom_classes/` automatically on `available_from_my_class` at `models/custom_class.rb`

I tried:

```rb
class CustomClass < ApplicationRecord
    def self.available_from_my_class
        [
            # Load all the Subclasses from the folder custom_classes
            CustomClasses::Subclasses.all
            # got the error uninitialized constant  CustomClasses::Subclasses

        ]

    end

end
```

But didn`t work.

Comment: @mechnicov, an array with subclasses automatically instead of declaring each subclass

Comment: Use `descendants` method for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '**/')]
```

And all files from subfolder will be autoloaded

```
CustomClass.descendants
```

returns descendants of class

Comment: thanks, I will try that. Do I need to use both, `config.autoload_paths` and `descendants method` together?

Comment: First one autoloads constants, second returns array of subclasses

Comment: Thanks for replay @mechnicov, i added, `config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '**/')]` to the file `config/development.rb`, and `CustomClass.descendants`, but it returns an empty `[]` array.

Comment: But your answer helped me find the solution, and I found the solution on this StackOverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888313/ror-mymodel-descendants-returns-in-a-view-after-the-first-call